# Define a function to iterate over a tensor before the running phase

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensor

I'm defining a loss function in which I must iterate over the values of a tensor. Of course, this is a python function coded before the training phase and I'm struggling on how to define a for loop on the tensor. In this tensor, there are some zeros and other numbers but I don't know how many, it depends on the training file of the current batch. Could be 2, 5, 10, ... I don't know so I can't use a fixed value. Here an example

```
points = tf.constant([[[0], [1], [0], [2], [1], [0], [2], [2], [0], [1]],
                      [[1], [2], [0], [0], [1], [0], [1], [2], [0], [2]],
                      [[0], [2], [1], [0], [2], [0], [1], [2], [0], [1]]], dtype=tf.float32)
max_indices = tf.reduce_max(points[:1])
for index in xrange(max_indices): # error here
    # do stuff
```

This is the error

```
TypeError: an integer is required
```

So I've tried in another way using this

```
points = tf.constant([[[0], [1], [0], [2], [1], [0], [2], [2], [0], [1]],
                      [[1], [2], [0], [0], [1], [0], [1], [2], [0], [2]],
                      [[0], [2], [1], [0], [2], [0], [1], [2], [0], [1]]], dtype=tf.float32)
items, _ = tf.unique(tf.reshape(points[:1], [-1]))
for item in tf.unstack(items): # error here
    # do stuff
```

And the error is

```
ValueError: Cannot infer num from shape (?,)
```

Of course, these errors are given because in the definition phase I don't have values but I don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming based on "in the definition phase I don't have values" that you are in a session when you need to iterate on your dataset.

You can use a `tf.while_loop(cond, body, loop_vars)` and add an end condition to the end of every tensor. This should be some value that would not show up in your dataset otherwise. For example, if your dataset contains only positive real numbers, you can use `-1` as your end condition.

Basically, `tf.while_loop(cond, body, loop_vars)` first calls `cond` which should return a boolean tensor. Meanwhile, if `cond` does not return false, `body` will be called with `loop_vars`. Note that everything you want to use in your loop should be contained in `loop_vars`. Global variables and variables outside of the `loop_vars` context won't work.

So you can use `t = tf.constant(0)` as a timestep, and increment it each pass through `body`. Then, in `cond`, you can check if your dataset `x` equals your end condition by using `x[t]` to get the value at every iteration. If it equals this end condition, you have fully iterated through your tensor and `cond` should return false. Otherwise, `cond` should return true, and you can then use `t` as an iterator for some dataset `x` by using `x[t]` in your `body`.

This is what I used to solve iterating over variable length sentences in an RNN. I used `<end>` as my end condition, and it works well enough. I hope this also works for you!